# Custom MessageDlg

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm trying to make a custom messagedlg in borland c++ builder. But the code bellow instead to change button captions, creates new buttons on left upper corner of dialog form.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "frmMsgDlg.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
int __fastcall MsgDlg( const String Msg, TMsgDlgType DlgType, TMsgDlgButtons Buttons, const String* Captions, int Captions_maxidx )
{
  int m = 0;
  TButton *DlgButton;
  int CaptionIndex = 0;
  TForm* aMsgDlg = CreateMessageDialog( Msg, DlgType, Buttons );
  aMsgDlg->Color = TColor(clWindow);

  for ( m = 0; m <= aMsgDlg->ComponentCount - 1; m++)
  {
    if ( dynamic_cast< TButton *>( aMsgDlg->Components[m] ) )
    {
      DlgButton = new TButton( aMsgDlg->Components[m] );
      DlgButton->Parent = aMsgDlg;
      if ( CaptionIndex > Captions_maxidx /*# High(Captions) */ ) break;

      DlgButton->WordWrap = true;
      DlgButton->Caption = Captions[CaptionIndex];
      DlgButton->Width = 56;
      DlgButton->Height= 28;
      DlgButton->Cancel = false;
      CaptionIndex++;
    }
  }
  return aMsgDlg->ShowModal();

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
  int msg;
  String capt[2] = {"PO","JO"};

  msg = MsgDlg("Tre tentime dështuan, ju lutem startoni programin nga ikona!!!", mtInformation,TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK <<mbCancel,capt,2);

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates new buttons because it actually is creating new buttons, in the line:

```
DlgButton = new TButton( aMsgDlg->Components[m] );
```

You set the `Width` and `Height`, but not the `Top` or `Left` properties, so they will be set to 0 by default - ie the top left of the parent component.

If you're trying to change the caption of an existing button, instead of making a new button simply cast the component to a button (which you've just checked you can safely do in the `if` statement, because `dynamic_cast` performs a runtime check to see if the classes are related and returns `NULL` if it cannot safely cast) and modify it instead, like so:

```
if (dynamic_cast<TButton*>(aMsgDlg->Components[m])) {
   DlgButton = dynamic_cast<TButton*>(aMsgDlg->Components[m]) // <- this is the key difference
   if (CaptionIndex > Captions_maxidx /*# High(Captions) */) break;
   DlgButton->WordWrap = true;
   DlgButton->Caption = Captions[CaptionIndex];
}
```

That will allow you to modify existing buttons instead of creating new ones.

Comment: Great!  Nice to know it helped :)  Could you upvote and accept it as an answer then, please?  You can do that by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Is there way to use Createparams with aMsgDlg form?

Comment: You'd have to create a derived class of the message dialog form and add a CreateParams method, and create an instance of that form class directly.  If you look at the implementation of CreateMessageDialog in Dialogs.pas, you can see it creates a TMessageForm and then sets a variety of things based on the type of dialog you want.  Write code to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for boring, but how to do  it with this MsgDlg?

Comment: MsgDlg, as in your method?  Replace the call to CreateMessageDialog with creating a new instance of your message dialog class.

Comment: Can you give me a sample, please.

Comment: It's too big for a comment.  Post another question saying what you want to do, and someone will answer (I will, if I see it, but other people might have a better solution.)

Comment: Also, please upvote answers you find useful - it adds to the user's reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I have killed a bit of time to expand on your original message dialog button modifier. You can just cut an paste this all and it will run.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "frmMsgDlg.h"
#include <memory>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

int MsgDlg( const String Msg, TMsgDlgType DlgType, TMsgDlgButtons Buttons, TStringList* Captions);

TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int MsgDlg( const String Msg, TMsgDlgType DlgType, TMsgDlgButtons Buttons, TStringList* Captions)
{
    TForm* aMsgDlg = CreateMessageDialog(Msg, DlgType, Buttons);
    int i, j;
    TButton *DlgButton;

    aMsgDlg->Color = clWindow;

    for (i = 0; i <= aMsgDlg->ComponentCount - 1; i++) {
        DlgButton = dynamic_cast<TButton*>(aMsgDlg->Components[i]);

        if (DlgButton) {
                switch (DlgButton->ModalResult) {
                case mrOk:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbOK));
                    break;
                case mrCancel:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbCancel));
                    break;
                case mrAbort:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbAbort));
                    break;
                case mrRetry:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbRetry));
                    break;
                case mrIgnore:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbIgnore));
                    break;
                case mrYes:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbYes));
                    break;
                case mrNo:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbNo));
                    break;
                case mrAll:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbAll));
                    break;
                case mrNoToAll:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbNoToAll));
                    break;
                case mrYesToAll:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbYesToAll));
                    break;
                case mrClose:
                    j = Captions->IndexOfObject(reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbClose));
                    break;
                default:
                    j = -1;
            }

            if (j != -1) {
                DlgButton->WordWrap = true;
                DlgButton->Caption = Captions->Strings[j];
                DlgButton->Width = 56;
                DlgButton->Height = 28;
                DlgButton->Cancel = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return aMsgDlg->ShowModal();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    int rc;
    std::auto_ptr<TStringList>capt(new TStringList());

    capt->AddObject("mbYes", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbYes));
    capt->AddObject("mbNo", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbNo));
    capt->AddObject("mbOK", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbOK));
    capt->AddObject("mbCancel", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbCancel));
    capt->AddObject("mbAbort", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbAbort));
    capt->AddObject("mbRetry", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbRetry));
    capt->AddObject("mbIgnore", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbIgnore));
    capt->AddObject("mbAll", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbAll));
    capt->AddObject("mbNoToAll", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbNoToAll));
    capt->AddObject("mbYesToAll", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbYesToAll));
    capt->AddObject("mbClose", reinterpret_cast<TObject *>(mbClose));

    ::MsgDlg("Tre tentime dështuan, ju lutem startoni programin nga ikona!!!",
        mtInformation,
        TMsgDlgButtons() << mbYes << mbNo << mbOK << mbCancel << mbAbort <<
        mbRetry << mbIgnore << mbAll << mbNoToAll << mbYesToAll << mbClose,
        capt.get());

    Close();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```